# CoroutineWorker crashes with no getForegroundInfo

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm attempting to migrate some network calls to WorkManager CoroutineWorkers, to take advantage of the automatic retries on failure and scheduling powers.

This is the worker I wrote:

```
@HiltWorker
class RefreshSubscriptionDetailsWorker
@AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters
) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

The code in BaseApplication which configures the request:

```
        val refreshSubscriptionDetailsRequest =
            OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<RefreshSubscriptionDetailsWorker>()
                .build()

        WorkManager
            .getInstance(applicationContext)
            .enqueue(refreshSubscriptionDetailsRequest)
```

I've followed the instructions in the documentation to ensure Hilt is injected correctly:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            tools:node="remove">
        </provider>
```

```
    @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
```

The problem I'm having is that when it's queued, it crashes with the below exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not implemented
       at androidx.work.CoroutineWorker.getForegroundInfo$suspendImpl(CoroutineWorker.kt:100)
       at androidx.work.CoroutineWorker.getForegroundInfo()
       at androidx.work.CoroutineWorker$getForegroundInfoAsync$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineWorker.kt:134)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

I would expect that I would need to implement the getForegroundInfo function if I was going to be using an Expedited request, but I shouldn't need to in this instance, as I'm not asking for an expedited request, or so I've been led to believe by the absense of getForegroundInfo implementations in tutorials, and the patch notes which indicate that you need a ForegroundService for Expedited requests: [Patch notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.7.0)

I'm using WorkManager 2.7.1, Hilt 2.41, trying to run it on Android versions 8 through 12.

Comment: i'm running into a similar issue... Trying expedited, and the docs tell me to implemented getForegroundInfo, but that method isn't part of the ListenableWorker interface...?

Comment: Same here, anyone figure this out yet?

Comment: How long the task runs? I tested with `delay(10_000L`) (10 seconds) and it works fine prior Android 12 without Expedited request and ForegroundInfo.

Comment: Are you starting the worker from a foregroundService?

Answer (score 6):

You need to
override suspend fun **getForegroundInfo()**
in your CoroutineWorker class and return
public ForegroundInfo(int notificationId, @NonNull Notification notification) there.
It helped me

Comment: Where are you getting those parameters from?

Comment: If you ask about noificationId, so it's your choice. For example 112 or 345615. And if you speak about notification, you can look there: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification

Answer (score 1):

remove .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.DROP_WORK_REQUEST) from your workrequest.
val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<...>()
.addTag(...)
.build()
just do that , it was work for me

Comment: We don't use `setExpedited` anywhere in the code.

Comment: it's not a solution, you basically disable the needed feature, you could also just say - don't start this workRequest or just don't use `WorkManager`, so unprofessional

Comment: worked for me specially on old android like android 5.1 , 6, 7

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to override the getForegroundInfo() method of your coroutine worker. Kotlin Example:

```
class MyWorker(workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(workerParameters) {

    override suspend fun getForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
        return ForegroundInfo(notificationId, Notification(...))
    }
}
```

Let me explain it a bit. Using the coroutine worker, this happens in the following two cases:

1. When you call setForeground() in the worker
2. When you call setExpedited() on your work request while running on Android 13 or below. Because Android 13 or below ultimately going to call setForground().

Behind the scene, when you call setForeground() in the worker, it uses the ForegroundService. And the ForegroundService calls getForegroundInfo() methods to display the notification accordingly.

Now if you inspect the getForegroundInfo() method in the CoroutineWorker class, you will get this:

```
public open suspend fun getForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
    throw IllegalStateException("Not implemented")
}
```

You see, the issue is there. If you don't override the method getForegroundInfo(), ultimately it's going to throw IllegalStateException Not implemented error.

Comment: ```1. When you call setForeground() in the worker
2. When you call setExpedited() on your work request while running on Android 13 or below. Because Android 13 or below ultimately going to call setForground().```

Neither of these situations has happened, thus my question.